# How do I output the updatable sum of an array in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Well on youtube I saw the game Blackjack (which runs in the terminal) and decided to screw my brains out a little and create an application of the game. Since this is the first time I work with TKinter, I do not get the sum of all the points. According to the idea, you choose a random number from 2 - 11, add it to the array, count, and convert it to a random playing card. The array itself seems to be filled, but I do not get the sum of it, because I do not understand how it is done. Here is the code itself

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import messagebox
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11] *4
random.shuffle(a)
bkoen = 0
biggame = 0
count = []
robot = 0
curent = 0
current = 0
robot_current = []
global_current = []
piki = ['','','','']
dva = ["","","",""]
three = ["","","",""]
four = ["","","",""]
five = ["","","",""]
six = ["","","",""]
seven = ["","","",""]
eigth = ["","","",""]
nine = ["","","",""]
ten = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]

while True:  
        curent = a.pop()
        robot += curent
        if curent == 11 :
                curent = random.choice(piki)
        if curent == 2:
                curent = random.choice(dva)
        if curent == 3:
                curent = random.choice(three)
        if curent == 4:
                curent = random.choice(four)
        if curent == 5:
                curent = random.choice(five)
        if curent == 6:
                curent = random.choice(six)
        if curent == 7:
                curent = random.choice(seven)
        if curent == 8:
                curent = random.choice(eigth)
        if curent == 9:
                curent = random.choice(nine)
        if curent == 10:
                curent = random.choice(ten)
        robot_current.append(curent)



        if robot < 17:
          curent = a.pop()
          robot += curent
          if curent == 11 :
                curent = random.choice(piki)
          if curent == 2:
                curent = random.choice(dva)
          if curent == 3:
                curent = random.choice(three)
          if curent == 4:
                curent = random.choice(four)
          if curent == 5:
                curent = random.choice(five)
          if curent == 6:
                curent = random.choice(six)
          if curent == 7:
                curent = random.choice(seven)
          if curent == 8:
                curent = random.choice(eigth)
          if curent == 9:
                curent = random.choice(nine)
          if curent == 10:
                curent = random.choice(ten)
          robot_current.append(curent)
        if robot > 16 and robot < 22:
          break
        if robot > 21:
           robot = ">21"
           break


def stop_give():
        if robot == 0 :
            robot == ">21"
        print(f'У дилера {robot}')
        if robot > count :
            print('Вы проиграли')
        elif robot == count :
            print('Ничья')
        else:
            print("Вы победили")

              
def creategame():
        game = Toplevel(root)
        game.title('Игра')
        game.geometry("1880x1260+0+0")
        current = a.pop()
        count.append(current)
        if current == 11 :
                        current = random.choice(piki)
        if current == 2:
                        current = random.choice(dva)
        if current == 3:
                        current = random.choice(three)
        if current == 4:
                        current = random.choice(four)
        if current == 5:
                        current = random.choice(five)
        if current == 6:
                        current = random.choice(six)
        if current == 7:
                        current = random.choice(seven)
        if current == 8:
                        current = random.choice(eigth)
        if current == 9:
                        current = random.choice(nine)
        if current == 10:
                        current = random.choice(ten)
        global_current.append(current)
        

        current = a.pop()
        count.append(current)
        if current == 11 :
                        current = random.choice(piki)
        if current == 2:
                        current = random.choice(dva)
        if current == 3:
                        current = random.choice(three)
        if current == 4:
                        current = random.choice(four)
        if current == 5:
                        current = random.choice(five)
        if current == 6:
                        current = random.choice(six)
        if current == 7:
                        current = random.choice(seven)
        if current == 8:
                        current = random.choice(eigth)
        if current == 9:
                        current = random.choice(nine)
        if current == 10:
                        current = random.choice(ten)
        global_current.append(current)
        d.config(text = global_current)
        print(*count)

def button_give():
        current = a.pop()
        count.append(current)
        if current == 11 :
                current = random.choice(piki)
        if current == 2:
                        current = random.choice(dva)
        if current == 3:
                        current = random.choice(three)
        if current == 4:
                        current = random.choice(four)
        if current == 5:
                        current = random.choice(five)
        if current == 6:
                        current = random.choice(six)
        if current == 7:
                        current = random.choice(seven)
        if current == 8:
                        current = random.choice(eigth)
        if current == 9:
                        current = random.choice(nine)
        if current == 10:
                        current = random.choice(ten)  
        global_current.append(current)
        d.config(text = global_current)

bkoen = sum(count)

root = Tk()
root.title('Главное меню')
root.geometry("600x300+150+150")

l = Label(text="Игра БлэкДжэк")
btn1 = Button(text='Игра', command=creategame)

game = Toplevel(root)
game.title('Игра')
game.geometry("1880x1260+0+0")
Button(game , command= button_give,text= "Взять карту").pack()
text1 = Label(game,text=bkoen , font= "Times 55").pack()
h = Label(game,text=robot_current ,font= "Times 80",width= 100 ).pack()
d = Label(game,text=global_current , font= "Times 80",height = 900,width= 50)
d.pack() 

l.pack()
btn.pack()
btn1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

What I tried was already prescribed, but I expected to be at the top of a number that is updated when you take maps.

Comment: Your code is not working. It throws `NameError: name 'btn' is not defined`. Also it's too long. Make it as shorter as possible (see [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) principles)

Answer (score 0):

> I do not get the sum of all the points. According to the idea chooses
> a random number from 2 - 11, added to the array count and converted to
> a random playing card. The array itself seems to be filled, but I do
> not get the sum of it, because I do not understand how it is done.

Move both `bkoen = sum(count)` to `creategame()` and `button_give(`) function.

```
print(*count)
        bkoen = sum(count)
        text1.configure(text=bkoen)
```

Comment `#btn.pack()`

Split two line.

```
text1 = Label(game, font= "Times 55")
text1.pack()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: There are no widgets in  Toplevel() functions

Comment: thank you I thought long and hard about the solution to this problem